# Django forms split based on model type

Tags: django

Django forms  split based on  model type

```
    models.py

    TYPE = (
        ('general', 'General'),
        ('category2', 'Category2'),  
    )

    class Test(models.Model):
        type = models.CharField(max_length=765, choices=TYPE)


    forms.py

    class TestForm(ModelForm):

        class Meta:
            model = Test
```

Is it possible to split the form based on "type", make 2 separate forms based on model type

```
    TestFormGeneral
    TestFormCategory2
```

Update

```
    models.py

    class TestImport(models.Model):
        tests = models.ForeignKey(Test))
```

The above model pull out all the entries in forms, would like to restrict them based on type, rather than displaying the entire contents.

Comment: This is very unclear. What do you mean by 'split the form'? What would the two forms do? What would be the differences between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are just looking for the right QuerySet.

To filter TestImport based on Tests type you can do like this:

```
TestsImport.objects.filter(tests__type__exact='General'
```

Not sure if thats what you want tho